# ERROR: pull access denied for postgress, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

While learning Docker using Django I got some problem related to installing PostgreSQL in Linux Mint.

This is the code from file **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    web:
        build: .
        command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes: 
            - .:/code
        ports: 
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on: 
            - db

    db:
        image: postgress:11
```

Error that I'm receiving while firing **docker-compose up -d** command

```
Pulling db (postgress:)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling db (postgress:)...
ERROR: pull access denied for postgress, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

This error still raises after login in docker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is an issue related to docker-login instead you've a typo in your file at image name which is postgress:11 (extra `s`)

see: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Updated compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    web:
        build: .
        command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes: 
            - .:/code
        ports: 
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on: 
            - db

    db:
        image: postgres:11
```

Comment: I also did the same mistake, thanks